# Write plain HTML in Jade

Tags: html, pug

I thought it's possible to write pure HTML as input in Jade files but I get an error while trying.

For this HTML

```
div(ng-controller="TestController")

h1 Services list

ul(ng-model="test")
    li(ng-repeat="item in items")
        a
            | {{ item.name }}

div(ui-view)
```

I get the following error

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "app/frontend/views/home.jade" changed.

Running "jade:compile" (jade) task
>> Error: app/frontend/views/home.jade:2
>>     1| <b>hello </b> test
>>   > 2|  <ul ng-model="test">
>> 
>> unexpected token "indent"
Warning: Jade failed to compile "app/frontend/views/home.jade".
>> Destination not written because compiled files were empty.
>> 5 files created.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? I would like to see the header of that file (where the !!! tag is)

Comment: there is no more code, I just try to write in HTML in the jade file

Comment: You mean that this is all the code in your home.jade file? In that case we found the cause of error ;-)

Comment: In jade it's working fine. I am using yeoman and angularjs. The view is loaded by the root... I don't have to open html body ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently by starting with a pipe | this should work

```
| Plain text can include <strong>html</strong>
p
    | It must always be on its own line
```

[jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text)

---

Outputting plain text should look like this:

```
pre
    <div>Stuff</div>
```

Comment: I can't just put in regular HTML tags which should be outputted as is ?

Comment: you mean you want to output code as plain text? try the `pre` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just writing plain HTML code into the .jade file(s) you'll need to use the Jade syntax for HTML files:

```
 doctype html
 html(lang="en")
   head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript').
      if (foo) {
         bar(1 + 5)
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container.col
      if youAreUsingJade
        p You are amazing
      else
         p Get on it!
       p.
         Jade is a terse and simple
         templating language with a
         strong focus on performance
         and powerful features.
```

Edit:

To use plain HTML tags within Jade you basically got 2 possibilities:

`p Plain text can include <strong>html</strong>`

or `| Plain text can include <strong>html</strong>
   p
       | It must always be on its own line`

You can check on further details here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/

Comment: But I want to write plain HTML I don't want use jade syntax. So it's not possible ?

Comment: Well you can (check my edit or AlexG's answer). However, you still need to use a proper file header, otherwise Jade doesn't know to interpret the stuff correctly.